# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined，vue3+element-ui

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I just create a new project with vue3， then I want to use element-ui,so I use vue ui to add the vue-cli-plugin-element. Then I try to run my project.The terminal shows a warn:

[image]

And my browser shows a error:

[image]

this is the element.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Button } from 'element-ui'

Vue.use(Button)
```

Comment: Vue v3 is still in beta. It's highly unlikely to be supported by other UI frameworks yet. Stick with Vue v2 if you need integration with other libraries. See also https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/issues/20061

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about trying to integrate incompatible software libraries

Comment: You should use [Element Plus](https://element-plus.org/en-US/) instead, which is created for Vue3.